# Windows service template missing?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I go to create a new project, the "Windows Service" template isn't there!

Can someone please either tell me where I can get it, or provide a download link to it?

Comment: Did you expand the tree and click Windws as the subcategory?

Comment: @MystereMan There is no Windows subtree for me.

Comment: If you click the + next to Visual C++ or Visual Basic, it should expand to several other categories, one of them is Windows.  You click on that and then you can see Windows Service.

Comment: @MystereMan I am using Visual C# 2010 EXPRESS. I don't have those options.

Comment: Here is a link to a discussion of this limitation: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/8b9207c8-4b59-4740-b6c3-c5fb1d8fea56/

Comment: For VS 2015 it's under Classic Desktop section. Installed->Visual C# ->Windows->Classic Desktop -> Windows Service

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related however under a warning in [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says it is not available with express edition. However according to accepted answer, it looks like it is accessible in express too

Answer (score 212, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2015 I could not find the Windows Service template by selecting anything in left pane. Including c# -> Windows. However, when I query 'Windows Service' in the search bar at the top right corner, voilà, templates for c# or VB show up.

Comment: How odd. Does anyone know why this is the case? It makes no sense.

Comment: Use "Windows-Dienst" in german (VS 2015 CE).

The really correct answer would be the next one written by Dung which really brings it tot the point!

Comment: For VS 2015 it's under Classic Desktop section. Installed->Visual C# ->Windows->Classic Desktop -> Windows Service

Comment: The Windows Service template is not included with Visual Studio Express 2015

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related however under a warning in [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says it is not available with express edition.

Comment: Thank you! Works for VS 2015 Update 3

Comment: @David There is no Visual Studio Express 2015. The name changed to Visual Studio Community 2015.

Comment: @B413 You are correct, however at the time of my comment it still existed..."While Visual Studio Express 2015 editions still exist, they are deprecated and Microsoft recommends to use Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition"

Answer (score 90):

**File > New > Project > Templates > Visual C# > Windows > Classic Desktop > Windows Service**

[image: Path to windows service template]

The confusion is because Microsoft's own walkthrough doesn't give the full path to the project template: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I think there are way too many if they list all. But Windows Service should be there indeed.

Answer (score 41):

It it a bad documentation of Microsoft that causes confusion to many including me. Here is how: in the New Project you will need to DRILL DOWN by selecting Templates->Visual C#-> Windows Desktop (click on it!) then you will find "windows service" template on the right. see attachment.

I hope it helps.

Dunn.[image]

Comment: I think this is the point of the question. There is NO Windows Service template to be found. This may be because it is not included in Visual Studio 2013 Community edition?

Comment: For VS 2015 it's under Classic Desktop section. Installed->Visual C# ->Windows->Classic Desktop -> Windows Service

Answer (score 4):

For **Visual Studio 2010 (10.0)**:

You can navigate to your Visual Studio install directory and run `devenv /installvstemplates` as **admin**

OR

You can follow the documentation on how to create a windows service **without the template** [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76477d2t.aspx)

OR

You can perform the steps below to reset your Visual Studio templates:

1. Please open `Windows Explorer`, and navigate to  `<Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE` (by default is C:\Program Files \Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE);
2. Delete the `ItemTemplatesCache`, `ProjectTemplatesCache` folder;
3. Open `Visual Studio Command Prompt (2010)` under Start menu -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 -> Visual Studio Tools (run it with Administrator privilege: right-click the program -> Run as **administrator**);
4. Run the `vbexpress /InstallVSTemplates` switch
5. Run the `vbexpress /Setup` switch

OR

you can download template [here](http://blog.larmib.com/2011/windows-service-template-for-visual-studio-2010-express/).But oroblem is it is in vb.someone can convert it to c#.

Comment: In the top selection, I don't think you meant to include run as part of the command.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have installed the ".NET desktop development package.

1- Click on the "open visual studio installer"

[image]

2- Check .net desktop development then click on modify!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

[image: Screenshot described below]

Go to File > New > Project; Templates > Visual C# > Windows > Classic Desktop; select Windows Service.

Comment: Please add an image description.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct solution to your problem but you should have a look at [Topshelf](http://topshelf-project.com/) 
which allows you to create an application that can run as a console app and also install/uninstall itself as a service. I have used it several times and it is much easier to use than a traditional windows service with .Net

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@SimperT 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881270/windows-service-template-missing/30689355#30689355) : The same is the case with Visual Studio 2013
Just query Windows Service in the Top right search box and templates for Windows Service in VB and C# are displayed.

Hope it helped :)

[image: screenshot:]

Answer (score -1):

For Visual Studio 2015 (14.0):

Navigate to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\General\1033\Service`
and click *Service*.