# best approach in using windows service in ASP.NET and how to configure it

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services

how can i use the windows service? will i put in my project as an internal code? or make a new asp.net project and call that project using windows service? thanks!

Comment: What do you mean?  A Windows Service is generally a separate application host than an ASP.NET web application.  (Unless you're building a self-contained WebAPI inside a Windows Service or something like that?)  It's not clear what you're trying to describe or ask.

Comment: ohh, im new to windows services, i will make a daily alert for email in my asp.net code. and i am planning to use windows service in aps.net

Comment: Well, you can certainly create a Windows Service application and run that on the web server (or any server).  What exactly is the issue you're facing?

Comment: my daily emails has conditions, not only email to everyone, but sending email to specific persons with a condition. andi dont know how to start, will i make a new web app just for the windows service? or i can implement it in my current web app project?

Comment: It would be a separate project, likely in the same solution.  A Windows Service is a separate application from the web app.  They can share code from common class libraries which would hold the actual logic of the applications, but would be separate application instances.

Comment: but i am missing the windows service template in my Visual Studio 2015

Comment: This has a few suggestions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881270/windows-service-template-missing

Comment: I highly suggest reading the material here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

> best approach in using windows service in ASP.NET and how to configure it

You can't.

ASP.Net runs on an application server and responds to incoming user requests, typically over IIS. they're instantiated on demand and killed when idle or expired.

Windows Services are run by Windows, using the Service Control Manager and run continuously and are not killed unless the machine restarts or the Service Control Manager requests that they stop.

They're incompatible technologies.

Your question is like asking "What's the best kind of veal to serve to a vegetarian?"