# Is there a replacement for a Windows Service Application in Visual Studio Community 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I want to make a windows service but I do not see a template or reference to anything like that in Visual Studio Community Edition 2017. Is there something else that replaced windows services, or has the nomenclature changed?

If not, is there a place I can download a windows service application template for c# .net 4.5?  When I look online I do not see any templates for C# except "xUnit Test Project Template"

Where are the templates?

EDIT:

It turns out my installation did not complete. It was giving an error during installation so I had to delete some temporary files and then it finished installing, and now all of the templates including windows service are there.

Comment: does this still apply? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9881270/windows-service-template-missing

Comment: I saw that earlier and tried everything they said, no templates are to be found even when I search online. It is strange. I am probably doing something wrong. Do you know, in general, are Windows Service applications still in use and current or have they been replaced with something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most recent .NET based Windows NT Service development that I have seen had developed using TopShelf:

https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf

You create a Windows application and import the TopShelf libraries using Nuget.

Comment: Thanks that looks good, I'll give it a try. Looks better than a template!